# Socket time out implementation

Tags: c, linux, client-server

I'm doing creating a DNS client and I need to implement a socket timeout in that. I couldn't find much information about the socket time out on the internet. So, I want a code for socket timeout and also where should i implement the socket timeout in my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For 100 ms timeout you need to do the following before you go into blocking read, if you are using UDP for DNS in the client:

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 100000;
if (setsockopt(receive_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(tv)) < 0) {
    perror("Error");
}
```